# POST JSON request with AFNetworking 2.0 is not working

Tags: json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Actually, I have sub-classed AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to make a service call. The requesting service call is POST with JSON data, refer the below code for reference

// Constructing JSON data in dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *createProfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[createProfile setObject:@"XXXX" forKey:@"FirstName"];
[createProfile setObject:@"Kumar" forKey:@"MiddleName"];
[createProfile setObject:@"V" forKey:@"LastName"];
[createProfile setObject:@"xxxxxxxx@sify.com" forKey:@"email"];
[createProfile setObject:@"asdasdasd" forKey:@"Password"];
[createProfile setObject:@"Facebook" forKey:@"RegistrationSource"];
[createProfile setObject:@"" forKey:@"Device"];   
[createProfile setObject:@"" forKey:@"FavoriteStores"];
```

// Service call configuration

```
self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

AFJSONRequestSerializer *reqSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[reqSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[reqSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
self.requestSerializer = reqSerializer;

AFJSONResponseSerializer *resSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[resSerializer setReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers];
resSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", @"application/json", nil];
self.responseSerializer = resSerializer;
```

// Finally, making a service call

```
[self POST:@"API/Signup" parameters:createProfile success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}];
```

After, making a service call. My datas are correctly populated in the database. But, service call invoking failure block and I am receiving error message like below,

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(Cocoa error    3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=
0x8e7a290{NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.,NSUnderlying
Error=0x8e7a150 "Request failed: unacceptable (406)"}
```

If anyone of faced this problem, can you help me out?

Comment: You can check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29886966/741197